# npm list reports missing packages yet I see some of these reported

Tags: npm

Running npm version 6.1

`npm list -0` reports the packages im using, but also a bunch of "missing" packages.  Ive also ran npm update but `npm list` still reports the packages listed below as missing.

Take for example the first package, mkdirp@0.5.1 , Im not sure why this is being reported as missing.  I see it in my node_modules folder.  See screenshot below.

```
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
npm ERR! missing: minimist@0.0.8, required by mkdirp@0.5.1
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by ignore-walk@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: brace-expansion@1.1.11, required by minimatch@3.0.4
npm ERR! missing: balanced-match@1.0.0, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
npm ERR! missing: concat-map@0.0.1, required by brace-expansion@1.1.11
npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by npmlog@4.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by readable-stream@2.3.6
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by string_decoder@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: console-control-strings@1.1.0, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by gauge@2.7.4
npm ERR! missing: code-point-at@1.1.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: strip-ansi@3.0.1, required by string-width@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: number-is-nan@1.0.1, required by is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
npm ERR! missing: ansi-regex@2.1.1, required by strip-ansi@3.0.1
npm ERR! missing: string-width@1.0.2, required by wide-align@1.1.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by glob@7.1.2
npm ERR! missing: once@1.4.0, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by inflight@1.0.6
npm ERR! missing: wrappy@1.0.2, required by once@1.4.0
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by tar@4.4.1
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by fs-minipass@1.2.5
npm ERR! missing: safe-buffer@5.1.1, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: yallist@3.0.2, required by minipass@2.2.4
npm ERR! missing: minipass@2.2.4, required by minizlib@1.1.0
```

[image]

[image]